# Enabling Hyper-V in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, virtualization, hyper-v

I've been following the guide linked below to enable Hyper-V in Windows 8 so that I can try out a few Linux distros without having to mess around with my UEFI bootloader on my machine, however, this option appear to be unavailable to me. Is this because I am using an OEM version of Windows 8?

http://www.howtogeek.com/76532/how-to-install-or-enable-hyper-v-virtualization-in-windows-8/

According to this guide, the option to enable Hyper-V should be available in the 'Turn Windows features on or off' menu however my menu does not display this option:

[image]

I used to use Virtualbox on my Windows 7 machine but thought I had better try the built in functionality of Windows 8 so can someone confirm whether or not I need the Pro version of Windows 8 to do this as there seems to be mixed signals coming from a general Google search on the topic.

Comment: If you have the Core version of Windows 8 you are unlikely going to be able to enable it.  I would find a chart that compares features and confirm

Answer (score 4):

You need Pro and it has to be 64-bit.

From Microsoft's [Windows 8 system requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/system-requirements):

> Client Hyper-V requires a 64-bit system with second level address
>   translation (SLAT) capabilities and additional 2 GB of RAM (Windows 8
>   Pro only)